# In a group of 12 scores, the largest score is increased by 36 points. What effect will this have on the mean of the scores?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, mean

I know that the mean would increase by 3 points. I just want a statistical(mathematical) approach.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

If

$$ \mathbf{x} = \{x_{1}, x_{2},...,x_n\}$$

Then the mean is given by

$$ \bar{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}} $$

Increasing any amount by some value $a$ would lead to

$$ \bar{\mathbf{x}}'=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_{i})} +a\right) $$
$$\bar{\mathbf{x}}'=\bar{\mathbf{x}}+\frac{a}{n}$$

In other words the mean is increased by $\frac{a}{n}$

In your case $a$ is $36$ and $n$ is $12$ therefore the increase to the mean is $\frac{36}{12}=3$